# Ideals on Rings?How do i Define them?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How do I define all the possible ideals of a given Ring-Set? Example on $Z(m)$. Do I stop when I find enough ideals that their union  give's me my given set??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the answer to your question is "No": let $R$ be a commutative (to keep things simple) ring. Then every element $x\in R$ yields the principal ideal $Rx$ and the union of all principal ideals equals $R$. However $R$ might possess non-principal ideals.

If by $Z(m)$ you mean the integers modulo $m$, then the answer is "Yes": all ideals of this ring are principal, since the ring itself is a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}$, in which all ideals are principal.

Comment: So there is no general rule on defining the ideals of a ring you just search for them not knowing if have found them all?